# How to pack a UWP library using PackageReference?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, uwp, msbuild, nuget

I'm working on a UWP library ([this one](https://github.com/Sergio0694/UICompositionAnimations)) and I've just upgraded the target version to the 16299 SDK.
This also caused the NuGet references to be migrated from the project.json file to the .csproj file as `PackageReference`, which in theory sounds perfectly fine.

But, after trying to publish a beta version of the NuGet package (generated as usual with `nuget pack`), I noticed that the library dependencies were not being added correctly, and I started getting exceptions saying that a given type was missing (as its dependency was missing).

I found [this issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5979) that does in fact confirm that `nuget pack` doesn't support `PackageReference` dependencies yet.

I've tried using MSBuild by following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets) and tried with:

`>msbuild /t:pack UICompositionAnimations.csproj /p:NuspecFile=UICompositionAnimations.nuspec /p:Configuration=Release`

but I ended up with [quite a few errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skne1.png).

> What is the right way of packaging for NuGet a UWP library using `PackageReference`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Open the specified line in the targets file, and you should easily see what kind of mistake you made in your project file. Don't ever post a picture, when the error message can be easily pasted as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to pack a UWP library using PackageReference?

Just as you know, the `nuget.exe pack` currently doesn't support package reference based projects and the feature "[Allow project reference DLLs to be added to the parent nupkg for pack target like IncludeReferencedProjects in nuget.exe](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891)"  is in progress.

As a workaround, you can manually including the dependency in the `.nupsec` file, following is my `.nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>ClassLibrary1</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll" target="lib\uap10.0"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

After pack this `.nuspec` file, the package will be generated with dependency `Newtonsoft.Json`:

[image]

See [Create UWP packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-uwp-packages) for more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Woah, so sorry for the delay on my end, my bad 
This worked, tried uploading a new package now and NuGet is showing the correct dependencies now, thanks!
I do hope a future update will make this process automatic again though.

Comment: Why we cannot using msbuild pack for UWP?